# When I go to print `chr(13)` from a var from my class"\r" is printed instead

Tags: python-3.x

When I go to "`print(ic.allopt)`", the `chr(13)` within my `allopt` segment prints `\n` instead of creating a new line. I am trying to print a new line when I call that variable from within a class. Thanks.

````
class Dialogue:
    def __init__(self, seed, prompt, opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4):
        self.id = seed
        self.prompt = prompt
        self.opt1 = opt1
        self.opt2 = opt2
        self.opt3 = opt3
        self.opt4 = opt4
        self.allopt = prompt, chr(13), "A)", opt1, "B)", opt2, "C)", opt3, "D)", opt4


openingscene = "hello weary traveller"
ic = Dialogue(1, "We came in and saw you on the ground, you looked pretty out of it, we tidied you up and tucked you "
                 "in. So. You have a name?", "My name is:", "Why do you want to know my name", "3", "4")


def initialclass():
    print(openingscene)
    print(ic.allopt)

initialclass()```
````

Answer (score 1):

In order to print a new line, you should use `'\n'`, or `chr(10)`.

The second issue you're having is that `self.allopt` is a tuple. In order to print the tuple's contents, you should use `print(*ic.allopt)` for expansion or `print("".join(ic.allopt))` in order to create a string.

In general, I suggest you to read on [string formatting using f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). I find it'll be a better solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is print is showing you the items within `allopt`, a tuple, without any formatting. Second, carriage return, `chr(13)`, is not newline but a part of newline in Windows. In Windows, the default line feed is both chars `\r\n`but I'll use `\n` for the example.

The simplest solution is to tell `print` to treat your tuple as a sequence of arguments rather than a single tuple argument.

```
In [1]: x = 5, chr(10), 6

In [2]: print(x)
(5, '\n', 6)

In [3]: print(*x)
5
 6
```

You do that with the `*variable` notation. Notice that the ASCII char 10 is `\n`.
Otherwise, you should format your string in a way you see fit. Maybe wrap that logic up as a method that returns a string ready to print.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

An answer to your question is also a correct answer to the following:

> **How do I concatenate strings in Python?**

I have simplified your example slighly:

```
def foo(self, seed, prompt, opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4):
    x = prompt, chr(13), "A)", opt1, "B)", opt2, "C)", opt3, "D)", opt4
    return x

r = foo(1, "hello mars", "pluto", "strawbery", "axe", "3", "4")

print(r)
```

The output is:

```
('pluto', '\r', 'A)', 'strawbery', 'B)', 'axe', 'C)', '3', 'D)', '4')
```

This is because `prompt, chr(13), [...]` returns a ***tuple***, not a ***string***.
You did not merge the small strings into one big string.
Instead, you created an indexed container, a tuple,) such that every element of the tuple was a string.

Please try the following instead:

```
import io

class Dialogue:
    def __init__(self, seed, prompt, opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4):
        self.id = seed
        self.prompt = prompt
        self.opt1 = opt1
        self.opt2 = opt2
        self.opt3 = opt3
        self.opt4 = opt4
        str_strm = io.StringIO()
        print(
            prompt,
            chr(13),
            "A)", opt1,
            "B)", opt2,
            "C)", opt3,
            "D)", opt4, sep=" ", end="\n", file=str_strm)
        self.allopt = str_strm.getvalue()

obj = Dialogue('strawberry', 'xxx', 'axe', 'yyyy', 'fgdff', 'fdgdfg')

print(obj.allopt)
```

You do not need to insert `chr(13)` or `"\n"` manually.
Python's `print` function will put a new-line at the end for you:

```
        str_strm = io.StringIO()
        print(prompt, file=str_strm)
        print("A)", opt1, file=str_strm)
        print("B)", opt2, file=str_strm)
        print("C)", opt3, file=str_strm)
        print("D)", opt4, file=str_strm)
        self.allopt = str_strm.getvalue()
```

Another way to concatenate a string is shown below:

```
merged_string = "".join(['str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4', 'fgdff', 'fdgdfg'])
```